# Play JsPath writes for Infinite Double

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, play-json

I am trying to implement a function writing Doubles that might have a value of Infinity (which does not exist in JSON).

Here are some examples of what I am trying to achieve:

```
Input: Double.PositiveInfinity
Output:
{
  "positiveInfinty": true,
  "negativeInfinty": false,
  "value": null
}

Input: 12.3
Output:
{
  "positiveInfinty": false,
  "negativeInfinty": false,
  "value": 12.3
}
```

So far, I have created an enhanced JsPath class, and added my function named `writeInfinite`:

```
case class EnhancedJsPath(jsPath: JsPath) {

    private def infinityObject(pos: Boolean, neg: Boolean, value: Option[Double]): JsObject = Json.obj(
        "positiveInfinity" -> pos,
        "negativeInfinity" -> neg,
        "value" -> value
    )

    def writeInfinite: OWrites[Double] = OWrites[Double] { d =>
        if (d == Double.PositiveInfinity) { infinityObject(true, false, None) }
        else if (d == Double.NegativeInfinity) { infinityObject(false, true, None) }
        else { infinityObject(false, false, Some(d)) }
    }
}

object EnhancedJsPath {
    implicit def jsPathToEnhancedJsPath(jsPath: JsPath): EnhancedJsPath = EnhancedJsPath(jsPath)
}
```

The code all compiles, and here is the test I am using :

```
case class Dummy(id: String, value: Double)
object Dummy {
    implicit val writes: Writes[Dummy] = (
        (JsPath \ "id").write[String] and
        (JsPath \ "value").writeInfinite
    )(unlift(Dummy.unapply))
}

test("EnhancedJsPath.writesInfinite should set positive infinity property") {

    val d = Dummy("123", Double.PositiveInfinity, Some(Double.PositiveInfinity))
    val result = Json.toJson(d)
    val expected = Json.obj(
      "id" -> "123",
      "value" -> Json.obj(
        "positiveInfinity" -> true,
        "negativeInfinity" -> false,
        "value" -> JsNull
      )
    )

    assert(result == expected)
}
```

The test is failing because the value of `result` is:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "positiveInfinity": true,
    "negativeInfinity": false,
    "value": null
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "value": {
        "positiveInfinity": true,
        "negativeInfinity": false,
        "value": null
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to modify my `writeInfinite` to respect the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look at `JsPath#write[A]` or `JsPath#writeNullable[A]` helps:

```
def write[T](implicit w: Writes[T]): OWrites[T] = Writes.at[T](this)(w)
```

`Writes.at` accepts a `JsPath`, which is how `write` and `writeNullable` preserves the path they are called on. All you need to do is wrap your current implementation of `writeInfinite` with it, passing the `jsPath` value along:

```
def writeInfinite: OWrites[Double] = Writes.at(jsPath)(OWrites[Double] { d =>
    if (d == Double.PositiveInfinity) infinityObject(true, false, None)
    else if (d == Double.NegativeInfinity) infinityObject(false, true, None)
    else infinityObject(false, false, Some(d))
})
```

And it works:

```
scala> Json.toJson(d)
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":"123","value":{"positiveInfinity":true,"negativeInfinity":false,"value":null}}
```